# Updating table in Schema 1 based on values of few columns of a table in Schema 2

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, hibernate

I will try to explain the problem with the best of my ability.
SO I have 2 tables in 2 different Schemas with few columns in both & I own only 1 of the schemas.

What I need to do is Update Table A in Schema 1 with a value from one of the fields from Table B from Schema 2.
I need to update only few rows in this table
The problem lies in when table A is populated the data in Table B is not ready with the data.
I am trying to this programmatically if possible.

Since, they are in different schemas & update size is comparatively smaller than the A's table size what should be the best way to do this?
SAMPLE DATA
**

```
Table A
orderNum | orderNumInternal | validity                | averageSales   |type
1000     |  5636            | 2020-06-30 00:00:00.000 |  NULL          |valid
Table B
orderNum | orderNumInternal | validity                | averageSales
1000     |  5636            | 2020-06-30 00:00:00.000 |  65
```

**
Here I need to update Table A with the averageSales value from Tabel B whenever the type in Table A is valid & there is match in table B for the first 3 columns

Table A is created in an overnight whilst I don't have control over when the data would be available in Table B

Comment: Sample data and desired results would be very helpful.  What does "Table B is not ready with the data" mean?

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have updated the question, please let me know if it still seems confusing?

Answer (score 0):

Would this not simply be an `UPDATE` with a `JOIN`?

```sql
UPDATE A
SET averageSales = B.averageSales
FROM Schema1.TableA A
     JOIN Schema2.TableB B ON A.orderNum = B.orderNum
WHERE A.averageSales IS NULL; --Unsure if this WHERE is needed
```

Comment: Well, I could do that but then doesn't join across schemas takes a toll on the performance? Also, the join on orderNum could turn out to be a huge list but not all of those would be valid ones as I need to take the "type" also into account for the update

Comment: Why would joining across schemas have any kind of performance hit, @PeeyushPathak ? They're still in the same database. In your example `type` isn't in `TableB` and you've given me 1 example to base this on...

Comment: Database queries aren't exactly my forte so I was kinda reluctant about going with the inter schema join but now that it makes a lot of sense to me I think I can try this by including the** type** field instead using averageSals in the where clause. Thanks for your advice.